# Grouping and filtering in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a huge table with the following format.

```
| Timestamp                 | Site_ID | Connected_status |
| ------------------------  | ------  | ---------------- |
| 2022-05-14 00:00:00 UTC   | 12345   | True             |
| 2022-05-14 00:01:00 UTC   | 12345   | True             |
| 2022-05-14 00:02:00 UTC   | 12345   | True             |
| 2022-05-14 00:03:00 UTC   | 12345   | True             |
...a few 1000 more entries for the same site_id (12345)
| 2022-05-14 00:00:00 UTC   | 32145   | True             |
| 2022-05-14 00:01:00 UTC   | 32145   | True             |
| 2022-05-14 00:02:00 UTC   | 32145   | True             |
| 2022-05-14 00:03:00 UTC   | 32145   | True             |
| 2022-05-14 00:04:00 UTC   | 32145   | False            |
| 2022-05-14 00:05:00 UTC   | 32145   | False            |
...a few 1000 more entries for the same site_id (32145)
```

This table captures every minute is a certain site_ID is connected or not. As a result, this table has several million records in it. I want to pull out whether a site_ID recorded both True and False 'Connected_status'. Thus I want the output to look like this

```
| Site_ID | Connected_status_change |
| ------  | ----------------------- |
| 31245   | True                    |
...and all other Site_ids where the connected_status has changed
```

I understand that I need to somehow group by all the Site_Ids and then run some kind of a filter on connected_status but I'm unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Site_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT connected_status) AS CONNECTED_STATUS_CHANGE 
FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY Site_ID
```

This should return the number of distinct values of connected_status in the table, grouped by Site_ID. You can convert that to a boolean using IF THEN or CASE, etc. as you wish.

Comment: you could also add a `having` clause (these allows you to filter aggregated data) to limit the overall result  `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT connected_status) > 1` add thsi after the `group by` clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 queries - the internal query will select all records with distinct - so you'll get only 1 record for true and 1 for false.
than use external query to "count" the record group by the site_id, having the count column > 1

Comment: Yeah, this is a good trick to know. It seems, for whatever odd reason, to be common in a lot of Oracle code I have seen, though it certainly works fine on any RDBMS.